# Code not running when trying to see if cell value is > 10%

Tags: excel, vba

My code is running fine and I do not receive an error but it doesn't seem to highlight the column.

```
Sub highlight()
Dim Data As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim currentsheet As Worksheet
Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Watchlist")
Set Data = currentsheet.Range("B2:B50")
For Each cell In Data
If cell.Value > "10%" Then
   cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
End If
Next
End Sub
```

For any cells that have value of >10% to be highlighted.

Comment: `If Cell.Value > 0.1 Then`. But this is easily done with conditional formatting, you don't need VBA.

Comment: "10%" is a string value, not a number.  How are your cells formatted?

Comment: Could you also post how your data looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
If cell.Value > "10%" Then
   cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
End If
```

Into:

```
If cell.Value > 0.1 Then
   cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
End If
```

Comparisons like that are done by mathematics, writing "10%" like you did is a string not a number, which means that you could have just as well written: "If cell.Value > "ThisFunWord" Then"  <--- this obviously makes no sense at all!